# How to Detect Window Width w/ Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, window, width

So this is what I've got so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Fonts!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="Hagin">Hello.</h1>
    <h2 id="Hagin2">Goodbye.</h2>

    <p class="Glober">Hello. This is a paragraph. It is meant to test this font. What do you think? Do you like this font? I think I do, although I'm not sure. That's why I'm writing this paragraph. Eh? Bigger you say? I agree. Let's make it bigger. Yeah, you know what, I'm using this. Allong with that Hagin thing. Some sexy shit.</p>

    <div></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var width = window.innerWidth;

    if (width < (300 + "px")) {
        window.alert("It works!");
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And when the window drops below 300 px, nothing happens. I'm using Google Chrome. I also tried just

```
if (width < 300) {
```

but that didn't work either. Ideas?

Comment: your code only executes **ONCE** when the page loads, then never again. you'd need to attach that code to an event handler, so it get executed on-demand in response to events - e.g. resizing the window.

Comment: How? What event handler would I use? Perhaps onmouseover for the entire document? Seems annoying...

Answer (score 0):

Try ...

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
    var width = window.innerWidth;

    if (width < 300) {
        alert("It works!");
    }
};
```

This will fire the event each time the window resizes.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is with the conditional statement. I don't believe javascript understands how to compare the window width (a basic integer) with a string ("300px"). Try removing the (+ "px") bit of your conditional so it looks like this:

```
var width = window.innerWidth;

if (width < (300)) {
    window.alert("It works!");
}
```

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
var resized;
$(window).on('resize orientationChanged', function(){
  clearTimeout(resized);
  resized = setTimeout(function () {
    var width = window.innerWidth;

    if (width < 300) {
      window.alert("It works!");
    }
  }, 200);
});
```

This would probably work.